# What is the name of the SQL variant used by FirebirdSQL?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have been researching the names of the SQL versions used by different DBMSs.

So far I have:

```
Microsoft SQL -> Transact SQL
PostgrSQL -> PL/pgSQL
MySQL -> standard SQL (ANSI)
Oracle -> PL/SQL
Firebird -> ?
```

I haven't found anything about this. I read somewhere that it's PSQL, but I'm not sure if that is true, since the search results for it return many pages about postgres...

Comment: [PSQL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-procedure.html) is the name for the Procedural SQL support in Firebird, while [DSQL](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.StructuredQueryLanguage#DSQL) is used to refer to the FB/InterBase "SQL DML/DDL".

Comment: Saying MySQL is standard SQL is like saying McDonalds is the pinnacle of haute cuisine. Both Postgres and Firebird are probably closer and more conforming to the standard than MySQL.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. `PL/SQL` for Oracle and `PL/pgSQL` are **only** used for stored procedures and functions. Regular queries are "just SQL". AFAIK only Microsoft has given their SQL dialect (the query language part) a name: T-SQL. I _assume_ this is because they don't distinguish between procedural code and DML. (Oh and MySQL's dialect is _really_ **not** ANSI SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the T-SQL name pre-dates the Microsoft takeover - so Sybase are to blame and their product also uses T-SQL (but a different variant to where the Microsoft one is these days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird simply has SQL, which is very close to standard SQL (probably closer than MySQL), it then discerns a number of different variants:

- *SQL*, the basic variant (although some of the old InterBase documentation seems to use this to refer to ESQL as well)
- *ESQL* (or Embedded SQL) which allows use of SQL directly in code (using a preprocessor), not used much these days
- *DSQL* (or Dynamic SQL), this is what you usually use when executing queries against Firebird from a programming language
- *PSQL* (or Procedural SQL) is the extension for stored procedures, stored functions, triggers and execute block